# Is it possible to append JSX at runtime?

Tags: javascript, jsx, appendchild, stenciljs

I have a stencil component that needs to append a child to a slotted node. Currently I do it like this:

```
const x = document.createElemet('x');
slotted.appendChild(x);
```

But I want to do something like this:

```
const xJsx = (<x></x>);
slotted.appendChild(xJsx);
```

The latter won't work because `appendChild` expects an Node, HTMLElement or DocumentFragement but is there a way to convert the JSX and append it at runtime using stencil?

Comment: You need a `ref` - https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @slebetman - The OP isn't using React, they're using Stencil (and I don't think a ref really makes sense here anyway; a portal or just `ReactDOM.render`/`createRoot` maybe, but...).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder React's own documentation says that this situation is exactly where refs make sense - integration with third party DOM libraries. However if this is not react and Stencil does not have refs then it's moot

Comment: @slebetman [Stencil has refs](https://stenciljs.com/docs/templating-jsx#getting-a-reference-to-a-dom-element) but how do they solve my problem?

Comment: @slebetman - This seems like the opposite situation to me. They have a DOM element (`slotted`), and want to render JSX to it. Hence [portal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper) or v18's `createRoot` (or v17's `ReactDOM.render`)... A ref makes sense when you need to *get* the DOM element for something you've rendered in order to *give* it to the 3rd party lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally no you can't

To elaborate:

JSX is just a syntax, it only exists when you are at an editor writting code, it helps you write this specifc language which is easy to understand by human and later can be translated to javascript and html tags.

When you say runtime, you are refering to browser's javascript runtime, browser's JS engine don't know what is JSX. As a result it doesn't work.

Now here's what babel come to the play: it translates your JSX syntax code into javascript that browser support. And it happens in build time. (you prebuild it)

The reason I said "Genrally" is, no one stops a person try to use babel to transpile JSX in browser with some hack... however I personally wouldn't recommand it since it's very inefficient and need a lot of work to have it working